# Can I remove "other" read access to /etc in Linux (CentOS)

Tags: linux, security, permissions

I know this is probably a stupid question. I'm guessing that a lot of "others" (various processes) need read access to /etc and other directories.

I am giving SSH access to an outside developer and I want to restrict him as much as possible to just the /var/www area. I was thinking of removing read access from /etc but realized that might break things. Was I right?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't fumble around with the permissions of system folders. Having access to `/etc` is pretty vital for many processes, some of which might not run as `root`. Simply said: It might be possible, but it's not worth the hassle.

I'd rather encourage you to set up a [chroot jail](http://www.serverschool.com/dedicated-servers/what-is-a-chroot-jail/) instead.

> A chroot jail is the common expression used to describe a section of a filesystem that is sectioned off for a particular user. On a web server, it is particularly useful for the security of shared hosting accounts.

So, you could "lock" the dev in `/var/www` – or even a subfolder of that – and let him do all he wants without ever being able to see any directory "above" the one he's locked into.

Building chroot jails is made easy through utilities like [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/), or is explained in various blog entries and how-to's, like this one: [How to build a chroot jail environment for CentOS](http://geek.co.il/wp/2010/03/14/how-to-build-a-chroot-jail-environment-for-centos)

Comment: Thanks, I did read about chroot jails awhile ago but my impression is that it would function as his, and only his, playground. But I will need to give access /var/www to various outside devs and various times to have them work on different sites in subfolders there. Not sure if chroot would work for that.

Comment: If one dev needs to work on only one site, you can restrict them to `/var/www/foo` – you could set up one chroot jail for each user, basically.